# How to inegrate beanstream in wordpress or php

Tags: php, wordpress, beanstream

My website is in wordpress. I want to integrate beanstream. I did'nt get any result for this. If I got result with php code it will also ok for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you lookin for beanstream payment gateway?

Comment: What did you do to find an answer yourself? And what's wrong with the information you already found? Are you using a eCommerce plugin?

Comment: @amit Yes im looking for beanstream payment gateway.

Comment: @NishaSharma Please take a look on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on:
[Beanstream PHP integration](http://developer.beanstream.com/documentation/your-first-integration/)

Just let me know if you need more help on beanstream...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a WordPress plugin along with Gravity Forms, if looking to use via WordPress: https://codecanyon.net/item/beanstream-api-payment-gateway-for-gravity-forms/10311923